# When do I NOT use the $(document).ready shorthand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I recently learned that

```js
$(function() { ... });
```

is just jQuery short-hand for

```js
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

---

Thus, isn't it best to have all functions in my Javascript style be a document ready function? That is, instead of having something like this:

```js
function myTogglerFunc(){
  $("h1").toggleClass("myClass");
}

$(function () {
  $("#button").click(myTogglerFunc);
})
```

my code should look like this instead?

```js
$(function myTogglerFunc(){
  $("h1").toggleClass("myClass");
})

$(function () {
  $("#button").click(myTogglerFunc);
})
```

If so, then why doesn't this second style work? When I have myTogglerFunc surrounded by $(), I get an error saying that myTogglerFunc isn't defined. So I'm guessing it has to be a Javascript function for it to be callable by other functions? Is this so?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're wrapping it in `$(...)` then `myTogglerFunc` is *only* defined inside of itself, and is not available globally any more. Defining functions doesn't need the document to be ready anyway, since defining functions *is part of* getting the document ready.

Comment: Use a single `$(document).ready(...)`, and wrap all your script within the callback.

Comment: Why do you think you need to wrap everything in `$()` callbacks?

Comment: `$(function myTogglerFunc(){` will call function once DOM is ready. Do you need this function to be called at that event? Objective of defining function is to have control of when to call, and reuse it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You answered my question, thank you!